# How to pass all props received from parent to child component in angular

Tags: reactjs, angular

I can pass all props from parent components to child components in react easily using the following code.

```
const Parent = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Child {...props}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I need to do the same thing in angular. Is there any method to do this? Since the child is a dynamic component I cannot use a predefined set of properties.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is Input/Output documentation](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs) and here is [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) documentation. Both can work for your scenario.

In short:

1. In the parent component add a @ViewChild. Something like this:

   ```
   export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {

   @ViewChild('childComp') childComp!: ChildComponent;
   ```
2. Child component you would pass @Input like so:

   ```
   export class ChildComponent {

      @Input() prop1!: string;

      @Input() prop2!: string;
   ```

This will get you access to the child component's and values you need.

Comment: For that, I need to know there are properties named "prop1" and "prop2". But in my scenario, I do not know what are the props in the child component. My ParentComponent is just only a wrapper. It simply pass all props to child. I do not clear your suggestion on this.

Comment: Then I am sorry but you need more information in your question, no one else will know how to answer. I gave you a generic answer in an attempt to help you move in the right direction. You are lacking information to give you the correct answer and hoping someone answers with the exact information you need.

Comment: Actually I need to write a wrapper for existing component. In this case the child can be any element of component. I need to pass all properties or attributes passed to the wrapper to the child component wrapped in. Using react this can be done easily. I need to do the same using angular.